# Google Chrome - Security Issue

Tags: google-chrome

Wanted to test the waters here regarding an issue I encountered while browsing a web page at work. We're sitting behind a proxy server. I'm not knowledgeable on the details of the proxy but can research with some folks I know at the security department if more info is necessary.

Thing is I was signed in at yahoo fantasy sports web site this morning and wanted a colleague to join a fantasy league. So I give him the league info and scoot over to his cubicle, not far from mine, when it happened. He opened the web page and my information was there. I mean, I was signed in on his browser (also chrome). I was still signed in so I went back to my desktop and signed out and then he also lost the session.

Needless to say, this baffled me and I'm very curious about the reason.

I don't have colleague's chrome version but mine stands at **3.0.195.27**.

Comment: It's your proxy, and probably ISA or something equally horrible. The NAT is broken. To confirm this, do the same thing on another computer at work with a different browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few possibilities here non of which are likely Chromes fault.
- The proxy/router cached a copy of the web page and the web page
- The host site uses IP addresses to maintain login
- Your chrome installs share a common location for cookies and the site uses cookies to maintain logins

First step if you are worried about this would be to contact the network admin and ask about the webpage caching or if chrome installs share a common cookie/history location (not likely). If that doesn't work you could look into contacting the website to see how they authenticate users and if they use IP addresses.

The important thing to remember on the second point is if you both access the site from behind the same proxy it would likely appear that you are both coming from the same computer (IP/MAC Address) to the host site.

Comment: Our installations do not share a common location for cookies.

I'm leaning towards the proxy or the website.

If the website uses IP address, I should be able to replicate the issue with any browser right? I'll try it with IE/FFox.

Comment: yes if the website uses IP address then any browser (even on the same computer) should work. I might try just firing up IE when your logged in with Chrome and see what happens

Comment: I'd go with either of the first two reasons - I've seen this before myself. The proxy can (and should) be configured to stop this.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a cached page in your proxy server.  This has happened to me at every place I've worked where we used a proxy server (I only use Yahoo! fantasy sports).  However, I was never able to browse my colleague's teams or profile.